# Best way to set default tint for UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

I use a lot of UINavigationControllers in my app.  I am using a UIColor to set the tintcolor of the navigationBar.  This works as expected, but I am trying to find an easy way to set a default tintcolor for all UINavigationControllers.  What is the best way to do this?  Is it subclassing the UINavigationController, or is there something better?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion,

...subclassing is the way to go.